# Asynchronous action inside forEach in NodeJS properly done

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, foreach

I would like to add a validation function in my cart building process. This validation function can receive an array, and for each iteration, check in database some values …

There, the code

```
async.map(eventPricings, function(priceItem, done) {
    var eventPricing = new EventPricing(priceItem);
    eventPricing.find(false, function(err, eventPricingFound) {
        if(err) {
            result.success = false;
            result.errors.push("The EventPricing identifier : '"+eventPricing.id+"' does not exist");
        } else {
            if(priceItem.quantity > eventPricingFound.quantityPerUser) {
                result.success = false;
                result.errors.push("Quantity exceed per user for eventPricing identifier "+eventPricing.id);
            }
            else result.pendingTickets.push({quantity:priceItem.quantity, eventPricingId:eventPricingFound.id, price:eventPricingFound.price});
        }
        i++;
        if(i == eventPricingsCount) done(result);
    });
}, function(resultArray) { /* Some stuff here */ });
```

The `find` method is an asynchronous function which fetch resource with server side. In the callback of this function, I'm doing my test, and if test passes I add my eventPricing in an array …

If I would like to review this part of code, promise oriented, and especially I would like remove the 2 last line which allow to unblock the process which are

```
i++;
if(i == eventPricingsCount) done(result);
```

Have any ideas ?

I'm currently use Q for other functions, but I don't know how can I do for this particular case

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for the non-answer.

What I've done was externalizing the code in a function that return a promise :

```
eventPricingsValidationService.isEventPricingValid = function(eventPricing, options) {

return models.eventPricing.find({where: {id: eventPricing.id}, {lang:options.lang})
    .then(function(ep) {

        if (!ep) throw BEV.errorHandler({codeHttp: 404 , type: 'invalidEventPricing'});

        var quantity = ep.pendings.length;

        if ( quantity > ep.quantityPerUser ) {
            throw ("Quantity exceed per user for eventPricing identifier " + eventPricing.id);
        }

        return ep;

    }).catch(function(error) {
        throw BEV.errorHandler(error);
    });
});
```

Then, using Q librairy and the Q.all() method , like that to wait all promises are resolved before continuing :

```
 _.forEach(eventPricings, function(eventPricing) {
        promises.push(_this.isEventPricingValid({id:eventPricing.id}, options));
    });

Q.all(promises)
    .then(function (results) {
       // Some code here
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that the async module? Doesn't look like you're using async correctly. You don't need to keep your own iterator, and you should be calling done somewhere every single time. Otherwise you'll never get your resulting array. The callback also expects `function(err, result)`. Regardless, there is a module which does what you want:

[async-q](https://github.com/dbushong/async-q#map)

Comment: Thanks @Timothy and sorry for the non-answer. I 've updated my answer and marked as resolved. Do you think is a effective way to do that ?